# What does *it in this C code mean?

Tags: c, structure

I need some help to understand the following piece of C code :

Lets say I have a structure as :

```
typedef struct
{
   char *letter;
   int dataSize;
   int Number;
}Page;
```

then :

I have in the same code the following line , assume x is a defined variable  :

```
Page *window[x], *it = 0 ;
```

I am wondering what *it is doing there.

Comment: Page is a type so a declaration of `Page x;` makes "x" a variable of Page type and a declaration of `Page *it;` makes "it" a pointer to a Page variable and a declaration of `Page *it = 0;` makes "it" a pointer to a Page variable and sets it to not point at anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating 2 pointers. You could split the line up in:

```
Page *window[x]; // = 0; //you should set it to 0 (or NULL) to prevent nasty bugs.
Page *it = 0;
```

`*it` is a `NULL`-initialized pointer to a `Page` object.

Comment: This is not quite the same as the OP code. In your version, you are also initializing window.

Comment: @DanielRose: you are quite right, thanks. I think something prevents me from creating an uninitialized pointer :)

Answer (score 2):

The `*` means "pointer". You should know this, if you are writing C code. Otherwise you really need to get some basic tutorial or introductory text.

In your code, the struct field means `letter` is of type `char *`, i.e. it's a pointer to character data.

The second one means that `window` is an array of `x` values of type `Page *`, and that `it` is of type `Page *`, too.

When declaring multiple variables on the same line, be aware that the `*` is part of the variable name syntactically, not the type.

So `int a, *b;` is valid and declares one integer `a` and one pointer to integer `b`.

Comment: @user3021170 That's strange, but ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Page *window[x], *it = 0 ;
```

is the same as

```
Page *window[x];
Page *it = 0 ;
```

so it is a pointer to a Page struct initialized to 0

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer to a struct of type Page. It is equivalent to:

```
Page *window[x];
Page *it = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

its a pointer to your variable, it holds the physical memory address that it starts at

Comment: Thank you for your help . I am still wondering why it is assigned 0 , this is what i really want to understand .